# Compass compiles preceding slash on file path

Tags: sass, font-face, compass-sass

My font-face mixin call is compiling a preceding slash in my css.  I have a sprite image using similar pathing that's working:

```
Compass.configuration do |c|
c.images_path='app/static'
c.fonts_path='app/static'
c.generated_images_dir = 'assets'
c.relative_assets = true
end
```

works ~ images/imageName

```
$sprites: sprite-map("images/sprite/*.png");
```

does not work ~ /fonts/q2.ttf

```
@include font-face("q2overlay", font-files("fonts/q2.ttf","fonts/q2.dev.svg","fonts/q2.eot","fonts/q2.svg","fonts/q2.woff"));
```

Any info around how I can tweak my config to remove that preceding slash in /fonts would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please share the resulting CSS and leave a follow-up comment?

Comment: @font-face {
  font-family: "q2overlay";
  src: url('/fonts/q2.ttf') format('truetype'), url('/fonts/q2.dev.svg') format('svg'), url('/fonts/q2.eot') format('embedded-opentype'), url('/fonts/q2.svg') format('svg'), url('/fonts/q2.woff') format('woff');
}  /* the generated font face reference */

Answer (score 0):

Have you set correctly the `fonts_dir` variable on your `config.rb` file?

From the official compass documentation:

**fonts_dir** *String*    The directory where the font files are kept. Standalone projects will   default to /fonts. Rails projects will default to "public/fonts".

**fonts_path**    *String*    The full path to where font files are kept. Defaults to /.

**http_fonts_path**   *String*    The full http path to font files on the web server.

**http_fonts_dir**    *String*    The relative http path to font files on the web server.

As you can see on [the official compass documentation](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/configuration-reference/) settings for sprites and images are different than those for fonts.

Let me know if it helped and if you're still stuck, please post your config.rb.

Cheers!

Comment: Yes, have dropped in the fonts_path as well. I'm using an assetfile in Rake Pipeline to build my app, and the equivalent compass configs I have are in the initial question, minus the fonts_dir.